# Code that returns analog read from arduino when specific key is typed

Tags: arduino

I am trying to create an arduino code that displays the analogread values of pins A0,A1 and A2 when 1 is passed through the serial monitor. The Arduino must stop transmitting values when anything else is pressed, say 0. It must start again when 1 is pressed and so on. My code (below) doesn't seem to work. Please help.

```
int oldv;
int newv;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    newv=(Serial.read());
    if(newv==1){
      //newv=1;
      Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(analogRead(A1));
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(analogRead(A2));
      Serial.println(",");
      oldv=1;}
    else{
       oldv=0;
    }
  }
   else{
    newv=oldv;
        if(newv==1){
          Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
          Serial.print(",");
          Serial.print(analogRead(A1));
          Serial.print(",");
          Serial.print(analogRead(A2));
          Serial.println(",");
          oldv=1;}
        else{
           oldv=0;
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You transmit text via Serial, so you should check for

```
if(newv=='1'){
```

You should also consider that there might come newline characters '\r' or '\n'.

Better you explicitly check for '0' or '1' and read but ignore the rest.